# Malformed code tag in answer rendering (but not in edit preview mode)

Tags: bug

Malformed HTML is being produced for this answer.  It only shows up in the full answer view, not the Editing Preview *(Update: after [a seeming no-op edit by @Braiam](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/556726/revisions), the bug is no longer visible...it may or may not be of interest if it's a latent problem affecting other questions)*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/556726/211160

[image: rendering of malformed code tag]

Offending HTML is the code tag:

```
<ul>
<li>Class data-members are written like <em><code    </div>
    <table class="fw">
    <tr>
    <td class="vt">
```

Answer MarkDown around the location of the problem is fairly benign, code tag in italics:

```
<h3>I'd very much like some pointers on c++ conventions</h3>

That's very subjective, but i like this convention:

 - Class data-members are written like *`mDataMember`*
 - Function are written like *`getDataMember`*
...
```

Comment: I just triggered a re-render.

Comment: @Braiam I thought about trying that, but thought the bug might be of interest even if it fixed it.

Comment: Interesting enough, the revision itself doesn't seem to have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/556726/3

Comment: And I thought only Jon Skeet is allowed to break the CSS, no?

Comment: @Rizier123 "SO breaks for Skeet", and [for a few others too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/211160).  But not only was CSS uninvolved in the problem, SO apparently still uses `<table>` for layout.  That must be why when I render it on my toaster the pixels get all burnt.

Comment: This is likely due to something changing in SO over time. I believe the normal question/answer views are not generated on the fly but rather they are cached permanently. The revision history is done on the fly, hence why it is different. The no-op by @Braiam simply caused the cached version to be rebuilt.

Comment: Braiam's edit wasn't no-op. When looking at edit history, clicking "side-by-side markdown" is your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Since the re-rendered post no longer shows this problem (and neither does the revision in the history), this would have been a rendering bug that has since been resolved. Note that the post in question is more than seven years old.

Therefore, there is likely nothing to do here. We can simply blame it, as usual, on ***caching***.